# Wait for data insertion to be completed (Load Data Local Infile C#)

Tags: c#, mysql

Still not having found an answer on the net, I leave it to you.
My question is is it possible to wait for the end of inserting all the data in the database from the Load Data Local Infile command (in C#) ?

I have a C # project where I need to be able to insert thousands of rows of data. So I use a Local Infile Data Load however the rest of my code continues to unfold even though the data is not yet all inserted.

If you have an idea, I'm interested :D

Thnak's in advance ;)

Comment: Can you explain more about your issue? If you tell the database to insert something and immediately perform another query involving that inserted data, that data should be included. You should never have to wait for the database to finish updating. What does your code look like? What symptoms are you encountering?

Comment: It would help if you included your code in the question. Paramecium13's answer is just a guess, possibly even a good one, but even if it answers your question, future readers would benefit from seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what API you are using but if the load data method returns a Task, you may want to await it, call its Wait method, or put the code you want to run after the data is loaded into its ContinueWith method (or something like that). Alternatively (or if the method does not return a task), you can try to fin a synchronous version of the method you are calling (e.g. if the method you are calling is called LoadDataAsync, use the method named LoadData, if it exists).